# SSIS OLEDB Dataflow Source using temp table but with Stored Procedured

Tags: t-sql, ssis

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
SET FMTONLY OFF

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp')is not null 
drop table ##Temp

select * into  #Temp
FROM dbo.employee

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

-- failed to map the column. error pops up saying .. No column is return. But if I use Stored Procedure then it would return using

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
SET FMTONLY OFF
```

Comment: It's hard to deduce *exactly* what your problem is. 1) Please click Edit to specify what problem you are attempting to solve. 2) Since there are differences, please also state whether this is a 2005/2008 or a 2012/2014 issue that you are running into. 3) Finally, please identify what you have done to try to resolve it, perhaps links to similar questions and articles that did not  sufficiently cover your case. You are not the first to encounter this, so before it's closed as a duplicate, I'd like to see if you can't provide a new twist on the issue.

Comment: it is BIDS 2008 R2, and I have a SQL Query of 100 lines and that is used multiple temp table and wanted to put that code in DataFlow task in source and trying to map source column into destination Excel. But it pops up with no column return error.  I am not using Stored Procedure in Data Flow.